open api generator kotlin gradle dsl - cant generate specific api endpoint
i am using open api generator kotlin dsl build.kts gradle task version 7.0.1 to generate spring 2.7.18 web clients
expected: generate 1x MeterApisAPi and 1x model
openApiGenerate {
    inputSpec.set("$projectDir/openapi/openapi.yaml")


    generatorName.set("kotlin")
    library.set("jvm-spring-webclient")
    configOptions.set(
        mapOf(
            "packageName" to "xm.xemongateway",
            "sourceFolder" to "src",
            "serializationLibrary" to "jackson",
        ),
    )
}

upon running gradle task, in gen-ed build folder, i see only the specified models gen-ed but not the apis (checked name specified is indeed correct)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

EDIT: added openApiGenerate gradle task
